# How to run an Android x86 Emulator in -no-window headless mode on VMWare CI Virtual Machine

Tags: android, jenkins, android-emulator, continuous-integration, vmware

I've got the following problem. I have a Continuous Integration Server (Jenkins) running Ubuntu Linux 14.04 Server on a VMWare Guest System. I would like to run a headless Android emulator on that Server for executing at least my headless Android instrumentation tests.

Since the VMWare Guest does not support KVM I am unable to run my Android emulator with the x86 or x86_64 ABI. Running with armeabi-v7a works, but I found out yesterday that there seems to be a bug in the Gradle plugin making connections to emulators with armeabi-v7a impossible from the Gradle build.

My question is now if anyone has found a solution to running a headless (-no-window) x86 Android emulator on a VMWare CI Server to execute headless instrumented unit tests. If there is a different solution, except using a dedicated physical machine, I would also be happy about pointers in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a link for the bug that prevents Gradle from using ARM emulators? I haven't seen this.

Comment: I guess that was the one: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190200&q=-has%3Ahost%20label%3APriority-Medium&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars ... But I am not sure, whether it is related to my problem at all. One of the problems I have is that I do not really know what the problem is or how to diagnose it, because my CI Build is unable to find a clearly running emulator. -.-